# Custom select with disabled attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have this script to make a custom select box.  I am overlapping Ul and LI over select. But I dont want to open UL LI when select is having an attribute called "disabled". can somebody help me to do that?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/47/)**

```
// Iterate over each select element
$('select').each(function () {

    // Cache the number of options
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    // Hides the select element
    $this.addClass('s-hidden');

    // Wrap the select element in a div
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

    // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
    $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

    // Cache the styled div
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

    // Show the first select option in the styled div
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    // Cache the list items
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
    $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
    // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
    $listItems.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
    $(document).click(function () {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<select id="selectbox1">
    <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
    <option value="aye">Aye</option>
    <option value="eh">Eh</option>
    <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
    <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if it is disabled i dont think you need to hide it wont be selectable anyway

Comment: it should be. but even if I add disabled attribute, onclick its showing mocked ul and li. Actually it should not do anything.

Comment: Something in your JS is cousing problems.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are making `ul` instead on top of your `select` with JS. I don't the reason for this but this is causing `disabled` to not work properly.

Comment: Yes, you are getting is correctly. I overlapping Ul and LI over select. But I dont want to open UL LI when select is having an attribute called "disabled". can somebody help me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.slbSelect.disabled {
  .styledSelect {
    background: lighten($disable, 14%);
    cursor: default;
    &:after {
      @include triangle(down, 6px, $disable);
    }
  }
}

if($this.is(':disabled')){
     $this.parent().addClass('disabled');
     $list.remove();
}
```

This solved my issue. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use enabled selector:

```
$('select':enabled).each(function () {

}
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4c4mhhac/)